# how to manage students (i.e. newbees) on a software project

Tags: architecture, project-management

I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage some enthusiastic adult students (with various technical backgrounds ranging from pure newbee to those with a more significant programming background) on a software development project which will involve creating a website for a small business.  My thinking is to use something like Joomla and segmenting the project among these folks.

I want to help them learn basic software development process on something "real".  I'd like to keep it simple and then go from there in terms of student and assignment management.

My initial thinking is to do the following:
- get a webhost account and give each student their own account perhaps through a reseller account on my side.
- use an SCM - probably subversion and do nightly cron based versioning

What else should I do?  Is there a better approach?  Is there a good webhost account that would work for this? (I was thinking a vps...but that can be a headache in terms of managing things like security)

I want to give the students a long leash so that they could learn from their mistakes, while NOT micro-managing everything on my part and ending up with a large amount of time sink hole where I'd deal with undoing problems rather than focusing on helping them learn.

I would appreciate any info/insight on this.

Ube

Comment: What do you want them to learn?  Just programming or broader IT project skills?  

Also, how real is 'real"?  Is there a real business which will act as a customer for this site or will it be you with a different hat on?

Comment: Just checking: are these students actually on the same physical location when they're working on this, or are they working from home?

Comment: APC - I want them to learn programming in combination of broader IT project skills.  As for "how real" - there is a real business which will use the site (i.e. www.acme.com for the Acme business)

Thorarin:  the students are working from home.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about management, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pair programming and Agile methodology works very well. Identify and make the leading guy into scrum lead. And if you really want to have fun - let them research and choose what technology they want to use to do it. In short - make it a collaborative effort rather than bunch of individual assignments

Comment: Thanks - good point.  Individual assignments are in effect micro-managing.

Answer (score 3):

Joomla is a mess. Use Django or Ruby.

I recommend you use WebFaction for a host. You can get a website, SVN, and TRAC for 6.99 a month.